# How do I batch delete entire rows that do not end with forward slash in CSV file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch, script, csv, text-formatting

I have a CSV file that is too large because it contains file paths as well as directory paths. I need to modify it so it only shows the directory paths but not the files themselves.

I'd like to know if it would be rather straight forward to create a "drag drop" batch script that deletes a row if it does not contain a forward slash at the end, because the file paths do not contain forward slashes at the very end of the cell, so this is the only common denominator to use.

```
Desired action:
If end with forward slash = keep row
If not end with forward slash = delete entire row
```

[image]

Comment: Given the rows you want to delete contain a file extension, I would use Notepad++ search, bookmark lines that contain `.mp4`, or `.thm`, and then delete the bookmarked lines. There are other ways to do this, such as using text to columns or regex, but a simple bookmark search and delete is the simplest.

Comment: I'm afraid this is just a small snippet of an extremely large file that contains hundreds of extension types so looking for a simpler way to do it if poss.

Comment: Is column D the last column in the CSV?

Comment: So, why does the csv file contain this data in the first place? It almost looks like a file listing created with a batch script. Can you not edit the source script and generate the folder structure only e.g. `dir /s /ad /b` or even `tree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

- Command line:

```
cd /d "D:\Full\Path\To\" & type "File.csv" |findstr /e \/ >"Output.csv"
```

- File .cmd/.bat:

```
@echo off

type "%~dpnx1"|findstr /e \/ >"%~dp1Output.csv"
```

Comment: This worked on command line level. Drag dropping the csv over the bat does not output any file though?

Comment: @Mastaxx like this edit?

Comment: That's done it! Had to add the > just before "%~dp1Output.csv" and this created the desired file. Thanks iTwasnTme!

Comment: Cell edit and bad glass

Answer (score 0):

This is not batch but, if you're open to an Excel solution, it'll work.

Use column E as a helper column. Presuming the first row is a header row, add this formula to `E2`:

```
=RIGHT(D2)="/"
```

This will return either TRUE or FALSE. Copy / paste that formula down for however long your data is. Sort by column E. Now you have all the rows ending in `/` grouped together and everything else grouped together. This makes it easy to select all those other rows as one group and delete them.

Comment: This is not csv solution! He ask for how to this do it in a csv file, I presume...

Comment: Hi Toast, when i do this the only sort option is "Smallest to Largest" for column E rather than "A to Z" which would have otherwise separated TRUE and FALSE. When I use "smallest to largest" it still mixes up the TRUE/FALSE cells so it's not grouped.

Comment: Correct iTwasnTme, i prefer a droplet we can use so we can hand it over to our operators for ease of use. If it's at all possible through regex batch script drag/drop/modify that would be ideal.

Comment: @iTwasnTme Excel can open and save in CSV format.

Comment: With no formula

Comment: @Mastaxx If every row of column E has the formula and every row is included in the autofilter, it will absolutely separate the TRUE/FALSE values. Both of those are common errors.

Comment: I know, but with formula, excel no more save the same files as csv.

Comment: @iTwasnTme Column E can be deleted after it's sorted and then [yes it does.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IO7z.png)

Comment: good to know! thanks. i never use this with csv file... thk

Answer (score 0):

Presuming column D is your last column and the CSV isn't formatted with quote `" "` marks around the strings, this will create a second file with just the rows that end in `/`. You'll have to change the file names to match your data. If you want to make the change in-place, you can add some lines to delete the old data and rename the new data to the same name.

```DOS
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (dataInput.csv) do call :processline %%a
goto :eof

:processline
set line=%*
set last=%line:~-1%
IF "%last%"=="/" ECHO %line% >> dataOutput.csv

goto :eof

:eof
```

If your data has (or may have) quote marks around the strings, you'll have to add some extra handling for that. You could pull the last two and, if the last one is `"`, then check the second-to-last.

Comment: maybe `"delims="` instead `tokens=*`...

Comment: Copy pasted the contents here into a txt file and renamed to .bat. Unfortunately drag dropping the CSV into the bat results in no outputted file? I can confirm that there are no quotes surrounding the strings and they are all separated by commas. Also tried replacing "tokens=*" with "delims="

Answer (score 0):

If the text lines in the CSV file truly end with a slash,
the following batch command will extract only lines that do
not have that slash:

```
findstr /v "^.*/$" input.csv > output.csv
```

Reference : [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html).

Comment: Afraid this one produces an empty CSV